# A sequence bounded by a Cauchy sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-sequences

In the proof of the following result, there's a little step (**marked with bold letters**) that I can't understand

> Let $V,W$ Hilbert spaces and $A$ a continuous and linear operator from $V$ to $W'$ with the property that $$||Av||_{W'} \geq ||v||_V$$ Then the image of $A$ is closed.

---

> Proof:
> Take $\{w_n\}_n \in Im(A)$ Cauchy, therefore there exists $w$ s.t. $w_n \rightarrow w \in W'$.
>
> For every $w_n \in Im(A)$ we have of course a $v_n$ such that $Av_n = w_n$ and by hypothesis we have $$||w_n||_{W'} \geq ||v_n||_V$$
>
> **Now, since $\{ w_n\}_n$ is Cauchy, also $\{v_n\}_n$ is Cauchy**

I can't understand why the bold sentence is true.

**EDIT:**
I think I got why it's true: pick $\varepsilon >0$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$||w_n - w_m|| = ||A(v_n - v_m)|| \geq ||v_n - v_m||$$

and now, for $m,n > N$ for $N$ large enough we have $||w_n-w_m|| < \varepsilon$, which implies

$$\varepsilon >||w_n - w_m|| = ||A(v_n - v_m)|| \geq ||v_n - v_m||$$

and hence $\{v_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Did you think about what happens in the real line? Look at $w_n=1$ and $v_n=(-1)^{n}$.

Comment: Just a guess: we may be able to employ the Comparison Test, or at least estimate the difference $||v_n - v_m||$ using the bound.

Comment: It's not true. Consider $\mathbb{R} $ with natural inner product. The constant sequence $1$ is Cauchy and the sequence that goes $0, 1/2, 0, 1/2,...$ is not Cauchy but sequence is always less than 1.

Comment: The $v_n$ doesn't look Cauchy. The norm of $v_n$ might not even converge with this assumption and in that case, it's not even Cauchy. Perhaps you transcribed the question wrongly?

Comment: I'm going to add a bit more context, thanks to all of you

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited my question, and I added a possible proof. Please let me know if you agree with me :-)

Comment: In the comments, is there some sort of confusion over the continuous linear operator? For example, the counter example $x \mapsto 1$ is not a continuous linear operator.

Comment: Initially my question was not well posed. @zugzug

Comment: Ah, okay, then yeah, the proof is straight forward with your edit.

Answer (score 3):

$||Av_n - Av_m||=||A(v_n-v_m) || \geq  ||v_n - v_m|| $ and the result follows as $(Av_n) _n $ is Cauchy.

Comment: I think you wrote the same I wrote in my edit, right? @Anon

Comment: Yes I just wrote it before you made the final update.

Comment: Do you understand how this shows the image is closed?

Comment: I'd say that $v_n \rightarrow v \in V$, since it's Cauchy. Then, since $A$ is continuous, we have $$w_n=Av_n \rightarrow Av$$ and the limit is, by definiton, an element of the image of $A$. Therefore, I started with an arbitrary sequence $\{w_n\}$ in the image of $A$, and it's limit is still in the image of $A$. Hence the image is closed. Is everything correct?

Comment: Yeah that's fine